# Convert Midi file to keypress evnts on a keyboard to see output on a virtual keyboard like VMPK

Tags: python, arduino, keypress, midi

I want to take a midi file as input in python or arduino and then decode it to generate keyboard press events to trigger actual keypress on a virtual keyboard like VMPK to understand/visualize how the keys are pressed.

I have built a big paino which currently reacts to button being pressed by sending keystrokes to the computer which plays music via VMPK which is a virtual keyboard. I want to be able to generate play music and simultaneously light up the corresponding keys on the keyboard so we can also see how an actual paino player has played the keys.

I currently have programmed 2 songs but it takes a while to get the timing right in code. I want to know if there is a way I can decode a Midi file and extract keystrokes and times they need to pressed and delays so I can emulate them.

I have read similar questions but they arent exactly what I am looking for.

Here is a picture of the setup [image]

Comment: Looks great! But this this question is not really for stackoverflow. "any pointers or tutorials in this direction would be helpful" is flaggable for closure, per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ill try to make it more specific and break the problem into subproblems

Comment: Do the tags mean that you are running Python on the Arduino? Would it be sufficient to react to events in real time? Which OS?

Comment: That would have a lot of latency, I have put the tags so that people knowing any of these might have a solution.. so just to make it searchable